# Latitude Longitude distance between two points as Great Circle and Rhumb Line in Python

Tags: python, math, geospatial, great-circle

Given my code:

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt, atan2, degrees, log, tan, pi, fabs

def _c(old):
    direction = {'N':1, 'S':-1, 'E': 1, 'W':-1}
    new = old
    new = new.split()
    new_dir = new.pop(0)
    new.extend([0,0,0])
    x = (float(new[0])+float(new[1])/60.0+float(new[2])/3600.0) * direction[new_dir]
    return x

def distance_rhumb_lines(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):      
    tenEtwelfe = 1000000000000
    r = 3443.89849 # Radius of earth in NM.

    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [_c(lon1), _c(lat1), _c(lon2), _c(lat2)])
    dlat = fabs(lat2 - lat1)
    dlon = fabs(lon2 - lon1) 

    if fabs(dlon) > pi:
            dlon = -(2*pi-dlon) if dlon>0 else (2*pi+dlon)

    x = log( tan(pi/4+lat2/2) / tan(pi/4+lat1/2) )
    q = dlat/dlon if fabs(x) > tenEtwelfe else cos(lat1)

    dist = sqrt(dlat*dlat + q*q*dlon*dlon) * r
    return dist

def distance_great_circle(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [_c(lon1), _c(lat1), _c(lon2), _c(lat2)])
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = (sin(dlat / 2) * sin(dlat / 2) +
                cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * 
                sin(dlon / 2) * sin(dlon / 2))
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))

    r = 3443.89849 # Radius of earth in NM.
    return c * r

def eet(gs, dist):
    return 60.0 / gs * dist

dist = distance_great_circle(lon1=u'N 47 27 59.60',lat1=u'E 7 39 55.6',lon2=u'N 47 30 32',lat2=u'E 7 57 0')
dist2 = distance_rhumb_lines(lon1=u'N 47 27 59.60',lat1=u'E 7 39 55.6',lon2=u'N 47 30 32',lat2=u'E 7 57 0')

eet_min = eet(100, dist)

print "Dist Great Circle = %.1f / Dist Rhumb Line = %.1f  / EET = %.1f min" % (dist, dist2, eet_min)
```

I'm not sure if this is more a math specific question then python. This is my scrapbook code to calculate the distance between two given points based on lat/long coordinates.

My code seems to work, but the result is about 5nm (nautical miles 1nm = 1.8km) too high as the result I get from my measurement based on my physical map where the result is about 12nm (my code shows 17.3nm).

What could be the issue? Do I use the wrong earth radius? Do I have to concern the projection type of my physical map in radius?

I now, there are libraries out there doing this stuff, and they doing it better ;) But I want to know whats the issue with my code before I throw it away and use a library.

Comment: Please, could you specify which formula you are using ? It exist various way to compute this, each one with it's own degree of precision, and more important, it's own computation. Is it the Haversine formula ?

Comment: By the way, the physical map i'm using is based on the Lambert conformal conic projection

Comment: To be honest, i've copied the formulas from the internet. But i think they are haversine formula. The Code in my initial post ist copy/past ready and represents 100% of my code.

Comment: This website provide a simpler implementation with explanation and an interface to get distance for coordinates, all that you need to code and test your own. http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html Check it. It provide Javascrip implementation but adapt it to Java isn't too difficult.

Comment: Also coming from this same website, an important note about calculation accuracy : Accuracy: since the earth is not quite a sphere, there are small errors in using spherical geometry; the earth is actually roughly ellipsoidal [...] local radius of curvature varying from 6,336km (equatorial meridian) to 6,399km (polar). 6,371 km is the generally accepted value for the earth’s mean radius. This means that errors from assuming spherical geometry might be up to 0.55% crossing the equator, though generally below 0.3%, depending on latitude and direction of travel.

Comment: I've used the same page to get the formula to python. I've just copied the Great Circle JavaScript Formula to Python and adjusted to run as python script. I still get this 5nm too much.